# GNU-Make: Remote command with ssh as the shell?

Tags: networking, ssh, makefile

Suppose I want to try the following:

```
SHELL:=ssh virtual-machine
# or: SHELL:=ssh virtual-machine bash
.PHONY:
foo:
  echo "foo"

# on the command line
make foo

# returns
Unknown cipher type 'echo "foo"'
```

Revealing that, more or less, "it worked!", but that `make` is executing the following:

```
ssh virtual-machine -c "echo \"foo\""
```

Understanding that this is an XY question involving `make` and `ssh`, my solution-neutral question is:

**How does one generate this remote subshell behavior properly using `make`?**

And, understanding this may be a bad idea or there may be a better way, my specific question is:

**Is there a way to customize the way make executes the `SHELL` variable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [GNU make's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html#index-_002eSHELLFLAGS_002c-value-of), section 5.3.2 (Choosing the Shell):

> The program used as the shell is taken from the variable SHELL. If this variable is not set in your makefile, the program /bin/sh is used as the shell. The argument(s) passed to the shell are taken from the variable .SHELLFLAGS. The default value of .SHELLFLAGS is -c normally, or -ec in POSIX-conforming mode.

Hence setting `.SHELLFLAGS` to an empty value should do what you want

Comment: ok, that is on me -- I should have checked the docs more carefully